# Spring Message Not Displaying

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am trying to do internationalization in Spring-MVC for the first time and I'm having what I assume to be a configuration issue. I have a NLS file that I named **NLS_en.properties** which I placed in my application's *WEB-INF\classes* directory. The file contains the following NLS string:

```
MSG_HELLO = Hello to the Internationalized World
```

In my application's **servlet.xml** file I've defined the following beans:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/NLS"/>
</bean>
```

In my JSP file I have the following tag:

```
<p><spring:message code="MSG_HELLO" text="You should not be seeing this text" />
```

When the JSP displays, of course, the message I see is the one I should not be seeing, so how do I have to configure my application so that I do see my HELLO message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResourceBundleMessageSource basename (as opposed to ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) refers by default to the classpath, so you should have it like :

```
<property name="basename" value="NLS" />
```

Now, depending on how you build, even if configuring correctly the message source, it may have been erased at the time you run the application. 
Do not place resources directly into classes (or any target directory in general). If you use maven place it directly into resources. If you dont use any build framework put it in the root of the source directory.

Comment: I had had the `basename` property set to "NLS" before, but I hadn't tried putting the NLS properties file in the _src/java_ directory. Do you know of any other way to handle this within NetBeans? I'll probably try creating a task in the ANT build script to move the file from some dedicated folder (say, _messages_) to the _classes_ directory as part of the build process, but I was just wondering if there was some other mechanism in the NetBeans world...

Comment: I have never used NetBeans. But with any build tool such as Ant or Maven (which you should use anyway) it is a piece of cake. Just make sure it ends at your classpath root

Comment: Well, NetBeans utilizes ANT scripts to do its builds, so I was able to add a _copy_ task to the **build.xml** file for my application. Thanks again...